# python: import into class namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

If I have a class

```
class TranformerTestInit(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Where should I add the statement

```
from regional_pos_tranformer import regional_pos
```

So that it is only visible to that class and not the entire module?

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: Also: You can't. You can delay execution but in the end `import` is just a fancy way to `exec` a file.

Comment: "So that it is only visible to that class and not the entire module" - no such scope exists in Python. You could kludge in such a scope by nesting the class definition inside a function, but you really shouldn't. Just make it visible to the whole module.

Comment: If you import inside the class scope, it will not pollute the surrounding namespace, however, it will still be visible anywhere `TransformerTestInit` is visible using `TransformetTestInit.regional_pos`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: But then accesses to the value go through the descriptor protocol, leading to really confusing bugs. Even on Python 3, where unbound method objects are no longer a thing, it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: @user2357112 Does it go through the descriptor protocol? In any event, just to clarify, I was not suggesting one *actually do* such a silly thing.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the class scope, for example directly above the `def __init__` line and at the same indentation.  It will then be available as `self.regional_pos` or `cls.regional_pos` (assuming you have `cls` bound to `TranformerTestInit`).

While it won't show up in a `dir()` of the module, it will still be accessible via direct access:  `TranformerTestInit.regional_pos`.

It is important to remember that whatever you import will be treated just like any other function, class, or data structure actually defined in the class -- complete with passing `self` as the first parameter when invoked via an instance.  You can wrap functions in `staticmethod`, but of course then calling them while building the class doesn't work.<sup>1</sup>  So while you can do it, it's probably not worth the effort.

---

<sup>1</sup> To avoid the `staticmethod` headache during class creation simply make that the last thing you in the class:

```
class SomeThing:
    from stdlib import widget
    ...
    fancy = widget(...)
    ...
    widget = staticmethod(widget)
```

Easier just to import at module level and prefix with an underscore:

```
from stdlib import widget as _widget
```

Comment: This is a lot more error-prone than it might look, since if `regional_pos` is a descriptor, accesses to `self.regional_pos` or `TransformerTestInit.regional_pos` will activate the descriptor protocol. This is especially likely to cause problems on Python 2, but even on Python 3, `self.regional_pos` will most likely be a bound method object instead of the `regional_pos` function.